# How to log only errors like 404 with chi in go?

Tags: rest, go, logging, go-chi

I'm using `chi` with our `Go` webservices.

How to configure the logger (`middleware`) so it only logs requests that ended up with errors (like 404) but it doesn't log successful requests (with status code 200)?

Here's our current implementation (with no logging at all)

```
r := chi.NewRouter()

if DEBUG_LOGS {
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
} else {

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to implement the logging function by yourself using the example from the chi package (for simplicity, I removed the colors).

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
)

const DEBUG_LOGS = true

func main() {
    api := &http.Server{Addr: ":8000"}

    r := chi.NewRouter()

    if DEBUG_LOGS {
        // create default logger/zerolog/logrus
        logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.LstdFlags)
        r.Use(middleware.RequestLogger(&StructuredLogger{logger}))
    }

    r.Get("/tea", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.WriteHeader(http.StatusTeapot) })
    r.Get("/ok", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) })

    api.Handler = r

    err := api.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// below is the implementation of the custom logger.

type StructuredLogger struct {
    Logger middleware.LoggerInterface
}

type LogEntry struct {
    *StructuredLogger
    request  *http.Request
    buf      *bytes.Buffer
    useColor bool
}

func (l *StructuredLogger) NewLogEntry(r *http.Request) middleware.LogEntry {
    entry := &LogEntry{
        StructuredLogger: l,
        request:          r,
        buf:              &bytes.Buffer{},
        useColor:         false,
    }

    reqID := middleware.GetReqID(r.Context())
    if reqID != "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(entry.buf, "[%s] ", reqID)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(entry.buf, "\"")
    fmt.Fprintf(entry.buf, "%s ", r.Method)

    scheme := "http"
    if r.TLS != nil {
        scheme = "https"
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(entry.buf, "%s://%s%s %s\" ", scheme, r.Host, r.RequestURI, r.Proto)

    entry.buf.WriteString("from ")
    entry.buf.WriteString(r.RemoteAddr)
    entry.buf.WriteString(" - ")

    return entry
}

func (l *LogEntry) Write(status, bytes int, header http.Header, elapsed time.Duration, extra interface{}) {
    // Do nothing if status code is 200/201/eg
    if status < 300 {
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(l.buf, "%03d", status)
    fmt.Fprintf(l.buf, " %dB", bytes)

    l.buf.WriteString(" in ")
    if elapsed < 500*time.Millisecond {
        fmt.Fprintf(l.buf, "%s", elapsed)
    } else if elapsed < 5*time.Second {
        fmt.Fprintf(l.buf, "%s", elapsed)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(l.buf, "%s", elapsed)
    }

    l.Logger.Print(l.buf.String())
}

func (l *LogEntry) Panic(v interface{}, stack []byte) {
    middleware.PrintPrettyStack(v)
}
```